# How do I filter and define a new dataframe by column value?

Tags: python, variables, statistics

I have a dataset with many columns. How do I run the .describe() function on a specific column "kilometers" when filtering the dataset to a different columns's string variable?

For example, I need the summary statistics for the "kilometers" column for all rows of data in the column Car Type where Car Type = Sedan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use pandas dataframe as your dataset format. In that case, filter out your dataframe, then use .describe()

```
df[df['Car Type'] == 'Sedan']['kilometers'].describe()
```

Basically you turn you dataframe into a series with a condition, then use .describe()

Comment: Cool, would you consider to accept that as an answer? :) @AaronELarson